# Deleting in gridview not working

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

i designed a page for admin to search users from database table using a Get button and delete users in gridview

This my source coding..

```
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" DataKeyNames="username"  EnableModelValidation="True" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="adm" HeaderText="adm" SortExpression="adm" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="mobno" HeaderText="mobno" SortExpression="mobno" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="branch" HeaderText="branch" SortExpression="branch" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="year" HeaderText="year" SortExpression="year" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="username" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="username" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="password" HeaderText="password" SortExpression="password" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="usertype" HeaderText="usertype" SortExpression="usertype" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CanteenConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Hosteller]" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM Hosteller WHERE (username = @username)">
                    <DeleteParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="username" />
                    </DeleteParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>
```

```
 protected void btnget_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string ConString = "Data Source=sheikha-pc\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Canteen;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString);
            string qry = "select id,name,adm,mobno,branch,year,username,password,usertype from Hosteller where adm='" + txtsearch1.Text + "'";
            SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, con);
            adpt.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                GridView1.EmptyDataText = "No data found";
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }

        }
```

this is the coding that i wrote for GET button

the problem is when i click on delete it doesnt work! please help.........

Comment: You will need to share your code for GridView1_RowDeleting() - are you re-binding in this handler?

Comment: @Cal279 no theres nothing in it.. actually when i got a error "Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove one definition." i removed datasource=Sqldatasource1 which was defined in gridview1... Then they showed me rowdeleting is not defined... so i tried but didnt work,,can u please help me

Comment: can you show us the `GridView1_RowDeleting` event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue here is that you are overriding the data source in your code behind. If you comment out the code in "btnget_Click" and add the datasource to GridView1 it should work to delete.

```
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" DataKeyNames="username"  EnableModelValidation="True" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="adm" HeaderText="adm" SortExpression="adm" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="mobno" HeaderText="mobno" SortExpression="mobno" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="branch" HeaderText="branch" SortExpression="branch" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="year" HeaderText="year" SortExpression="year" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="username" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="username" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="password" HeaderText="password" SortExpression="password" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="usertype" HeaderText="usertype" SortExpression="usertype" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

And the code behind:

```
protected void btnget_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }
```

This might not be what you want though. This will load the data on page load so the user will not need to click the button in order to get the results.

If you want the user to click the button then you will need to rewirte your code a bit and put some code in RowDeleting()  as @Cal279 sugested in his comment.

Comment: actually admin have to delete users as per year and my database is huge . So the get button extract the users he want to delete.. Thus get button is important.. Is there any other method?

Comment: Yes, take a look at this link and the answer from salman. You can manually add the button and write some code to delete the record. http://forums.asp.net/t/1726832.aspx?adding+buttons+with+each+row+of+the+GridView